# How to make a loop in R that calculates means of every two rows of several columns of a data frame, then continues for each resulting df?

Tags: r, loops

I'm having trouble making my code for calculating the 2^n-point means of several columns of individual time series data. So, it begins with a data frame of 1024 rows and any number of columns of time series data. It then calculates the 2-point means of every two rows of each column and stores it as a 512-row data frame. Then it calculates the 4-point means, which is the mean of every 2 rows in the 512-row data frame of means, resulting in a 256-row data frame of means. This continues until the 512-point means with one mean per column. It then feeds each of these column means into a population standard deviation function. The final result I need is a data frame that contains these population standard deviations corresponding to the 2^n-point means of each time series (i.e., of each column). Here is what I have:

```
find_fds <- function(df, max_bin = 7, export = FALSE, filetype = ".txt"){
# function that turns raw time series data into the fractal dimensions of each series
# requires df, which is just a data frame containing the time series (singular or plural)
# ensure the data is in long format, such that each column is one participant and the rows consist of each time (in ms)
# automatically makes values >= abs(1000) NAs, pushes them to the end of the column, then deletes the NAs and truncates from the end to 1024 time data points
# NOTE: The cleaning function takes .txt files, but you can edit this to any type of file you have, so long as they are properly called
  
#input_data <- read.delim("*.txt")
  input_data <- abs(df)
  
# Replace values greater than or equal 1000 by default
  input_data[input_data >= 1000] <- NA
  
# Shift remaining cells up in each column
  input_data <- as.data.frame(lapply(input_data, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
  
# Select the first 'final_rows' rows
  input_data <- input_data[1:1024, ]
  
# rename each column with "Participant" and the number of the column
  names(input_data) <- paste0("Participant", seq_len(ncol(input_data)))

  

## Finding population z-scores:
  
  
# Get the numeric columns (excluding non-numeric columns like participant or trial)
  numeric_columns <- sapply(input_data, is.numeric)
  
# Apply z-score transformation with population standard deviations to numeric columns
  z_scores <- as.data.frame(scale(input_data[, numeric_columns], scale = apply(input_data[, numeric_columns], 2, sd)))
  
# Rename the z-score columns
  colnames(z_scores) <- paste0(colnames(input_data)[numeric_columns], "_Z")
  
# return the z-scores
# return(z_scores)
  
# Finding population standard deviations of z-scores:
  # Z-score pop standard deviations:
sds0 <- apply(z_scores, 2, sd.p)

# 2-point means:
means2pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(z_scores), 2), function(i){
          x <- z_scores[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
          res
        })))
sds2 <- apply(means2pt, 2, sd.p)

# 4-point means:
means4pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(means2pt), 2), function(i){
          x <- means2pt[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
         # rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        })))
rm(means2pt)
sds4 <- apply(means4pt, 2, sd.p)

# 8-point means:
means8pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(means4pt), 2), function(i){
          x <- means4pt[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
         # rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        })))
rm(means4pt)
sds8 <- apply(means8pt, 2, sd.p)

# 16-point means:
means16pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(means8pt), 2), function(i){
          x <- means8pt[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
         # rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        })))
rm(means8pt)
sds16 <- apply(means16pt, 2, sd.p)

# 32-point means:
means32pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(means16pt), 2), function(i){
          x <- means16pt[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
         # rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        })))
rm(means16pt)
sds32 <- apply(means32pt, 2, sd.p)

# 64-point means:
means64pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(means32pt), 2), function(i){
          x <- means32pt[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
         # rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        })))
rm(means32pt)
sds64 <- apply(means64pt, 2, sd.p)

# 128-point means:
means128pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(means64pt), 2), function(i){
          x <- means64pt[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
         # rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        })))
rm(means64pt)
sds128 <- apply(means128pt, 2, sd.p)

# 256-point means:
means256pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(means128pt), 2), function(i){
          x <- means128pt[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
         # rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        })))
rm(means128pt)
sds256 <- apply(means256pt, 2, sd.p)

# 512-point means:
means512pt <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(means256pt), 2), function(i){
          x <- means256pt[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(#x, 
                       colSums(x)/2)
         # rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        })))
rm(means256pt)
sds512 <- apply(means512pt, 2, sd.p)
rm(means512pt)

# deleting each means data frame to make things cleaner
#rm(means2pt, means4pt, means8pt, means16pt, means32pt, means64pt, means128pt, means256pt, means512pt)

# getting population standard deviations of each n^2-point mean in a data frame:
pop_sds <- data.frame(sds0, sds2, sds4, sds8, sds16, sds32, sds64, sds128, sds256, sds512)

# deleting each individual population standard deviation list
rm(sds0, sds2, sds4, sds8, sds16, sds32, sds64, sds128, sds256, sds512)

# fixing column names
names(pop_sds) <- c("Z-Score_SDs", "2-Point_Mean_SDs", "4-Point_Mean_SDs","8-Point_Mean_SDs","16-Point_Mean_SDs","32-Point_Mean_SDs","64-Point_Mean_SDs","128-Point_Mean_SDs","256-Point_Mean_SDs","512-Point_Mean_SDs")

# return(pop_sds)

# initializing an empty vector to store FDs
FD_values <- numeric(nrow(pop_sds))

# a for loop for calculating each FD by participant time series
  for(i in 1:nrow(pop_sds)){
    
# log_2 of each population sd by participant
log2s <- log2(pop_sds[i,1:max_bin])

# log_2 of each bin size (just a vector with length of max bins)
bin_sz_log2 <- c(1:max_bin) 

# combines the two vectors into one matrix
df_logs <- rbind(log2s, bin_sz_log2)

# takes the transpose of the above and turns it into a df for modeling
df_logs <- as.data.frame(t(df_logs))

# changes the variable names to something constant 
names(df_logs) <- c("Log_2_SDs", "Log_2_Bin_Sizes")

# un-quote this if you want to inspect the resulting data frames
# print(df_logs)

# fitting the model linearly
fit_mdl <- lm(Log_2_SDs ~ Log_2_Bin_Sizes, data = df_logs)

# extracting the slope
slope <- coef(fit_mdl)[2]

# fractal dimension
FD <- 1 - slope

# outputs each calculated FD into the initialized empty vector
FD_values[i] <- FD
  }

# binds all FDs into one data frame and returns the result
result <- data.frame(FD = FD_values)

if(export){
  if(file_type == "txt"){
    write.table(result, "FD_results.txt")
  } else if(file_type == "csv"){
    write.csv(result, "FD_results.csv")
  } else if(file_type == "xlsx"){
    write.xlsx(result, "FD_results.xlsx")
  } else{
    stop("Invalid file type specified! Use .txt, .csv, or .xlsx.")
  }
}

return(result)
}
```

As you can see, the 2^n-point means absolutely devastate processing time and sometimes crashes R, as it stores every data frame from the last step, all of which need to be used for the population SD calculations. Let me know if you all have any ideas. Thanks!

I have tried using a for-loop, but I can't understand how to do it with differing data frame row lengths.

Comment: `rbind`ing within an `lapply` is an obvious inefficiency.  Do the binding outside the loop and you'll have an immediate (and probably substantial) increase in speed.  You may need to use `dplyr::bind_rows` rather than `rbind`.

Comment: The `rbind`-in-a-loop is probably the big performance killer as Limey says, but all your conversions from `matrix` to `data.frame` and back are pointless inefficiency as well. I would suggest writing a function that accepts a plain **vector**, and calculates the 2-point means of it. You can then wrap that in a  function recursively or in a `while` loop to get the `n`-point means you want to use. Finally you can `lapply` that wrapped function across all the column. You'll do no converting back and forth, a single bind at the end, your code will be 90% shorter and your run time much faster.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly `mean_2_pt = function(x) {n = length(x); if(n == 1) x else (x[c(TRUE, FALSE)] + x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])/2}` can be your base function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on the tidyverse and following similar lines to those suggested by Gregor Thomas.

First, create some test data

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate test data
set.seed(123)
testData <- tibble(
  Col1 = rnorm(1024),
  Col2 = rnorm(1024, 3, 5),
  Col3 = rnorm(1024, -10, 4)
)

testData
# A tibble: 1,024 × 3
      Col1   Col2   Col3
     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -0.560  -5.24  -12.9 
 2 -0.230   4.14  -14.0 
 3  1.56   11.3   -10.8 
 4  0.0705 10.1   -11.4 
 5  0.129   5.10   -6.66
 6  1.72    6.61   -3.88
 7  0.461  -2.98  -10.0 
 8 -1.27    4.50   -8.41
 9 -0.687  -1.77  -10.3 
10 -0.446   0.710  -7.59
# ℹ 1,014 more rows
```

Now solve the problem

```
calculateMeans <- function(df) {
  # ceiling just in case row count changes
  powerOf2 <- ceiling(log(nrow(df), 2))
  lapply(
    seq_along(1:powerOf2),
    function(p2) {
      df %>% 
        mutate(Group = rep(1:(nrow(.)/(2^p2)), each = 2^p2)) %>% 
        group_by(Group) %>% 
        # Adapt column selection according to your needs
        summarise(across(starts_with("Col"), \(.x) mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
        add_column(PowerOf2 = p2)
    }
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
}

result <- testData %>% calculateMeans()
result
# A tibble: 1,023 × 5
   Group   Col1   Col2   Col3 PowerOf2
   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>
 1     1 -0.395 -0.550 -13.4         1
 2     2  0.815 10.7   -11.1         1
 3     3  0.922  5.85   -5.27        1
 4     4 -0.402  0.758  -9.23        1
 5     5 -0.566 -0.531  -8.94        1
 6     6  0.792  2.50   -9.09        1
 7     7  0.256  4.74   -9.75        1
 8     8  0.616  7.69   -6.41        1
 9     9 -0.734  1.96  -10.8         1
10    10  0.114  2.13   -9.58        1
# ℹ 1,013 more rows
```

The number of rows in the output is correct.  To check that the numerical results are correct, it's easier to look at the tail of the result rather than its head:

```
result %>% tail(7)
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  Group     Col1  Col2   Col3 PowerOf2
  <int>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>
1     8  0.0439   3.24  -9.57        7
2     1 -0.00711  3.13 -10.6         8
3     2  0.0583   3.12  -9.92        8
4     3 -0.00579  3.17 -10.1         8
5     4  0.0451   3.31  -9.85        8
6     1  0.0256   3.12 -10.2         9
7     2  0.0197   3.24  -9.96        9
8     1  0.0226   3.18 -10.1        10
```

`PowerOf2` indicates the power of 2 used to generate the groups.  `Group` gives the ID of the group.  So the largest power of 2 is 10 (because 2^10 = 1024).  There is a single `Group` for this `PowerOf2`, 2 `Group`s when `PowerOf2` is `9`, and so on.

It's easy to check the results for `PowerOf2 == 10`:

```
testData %>% summarise(across(everything(), mean))
# A tibble: 1 × 3
    Col1  Col2  Col3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.0226  3.18 -10.1
```

... and for `PowerOf2 == 9` ...

```
testData %>% 
  mutate(Group = rep(1:2, each = 512)) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), mean))
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Group   Col1  Col2   Col3
  <int>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 0.0256  3.12 -10.2 
2     2 0.0197  3.24  -9.96
```

All good.  And so on.

**Benchmarking**

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark({testData %>% calculateMeans() }, times = 100)
Unit: milliseconds
                                  expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 {     testData %>% calculateMeans() } 153.4826 160.3116 166.356 164.1811 166.9798 334.0101   100
```

So an average execution time of 0.166 seconds to calculate all 2^k -group means for k = 1, 2, ..., 10.